# Multiple similarly-named columns in SQL Server result set

Tags: sql, sql-server, resultset

I am asking this question for using result set with queries in a SQL Server database, but I would guess it applies to Oracle to, and whatever other databases?

I have two databases, submit and response, each has many columns. Both have a column `submitid` which is what I do the join on:

```
select s.*, r.* 
from submit s, response r 
where s.submitid = r.submit.
```

I use a result set `rs`, and do things like

```
someVar = rs.getString(someColumn).
```

The problem is that submit and result have other columns with common names but the values are not always the same (such as, say, username).

If I run

```
rs.getString("username")
```

I am not sure which one will be retrieved, but `rs.getString("s.username")` says it is invalid, so how do you specify from which table you want the column?

Comment: Specify your columns exlicitly, and give them a meaningful alias

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**almost 30 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0):

First, learn to use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Second, you need to rename the columns in at least one of the tables:

```
select s.*, r.username as response_username, . . .
from submit s join
     response r 
     on s.submitid = r.submitid;
```

Comment: yeah, sorry.  Should have said r.submitid not r.submit